# If a woman is converted as a child and never learns this, what are her children’s status?

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism, contemporary-halacha

A woman is converted as an infant, but was never told of her conversion. She lives her life, marries, has children and grandchildren, and eventually passes away, never knowing the truth. One of her descendants does a DNA test and discovers the truth. What is the status of her children and her daughter’s children?

Related to this, before the truth is out, one child suspects their mother was an infant convert. Are they allowed to test to find out? If they discover the truth while their mother is alive, are they required to tell her, even if it will cause her significant distress?

Comment: what is a DNA test going to show in this case?

Comment: There are no "Jew" genes that show up in a DNA test, or any other laboratory test, for that matter. Being "Jewish" is a spiritual reality, not a physical one, that can be discerned through physical means.

Comment: Really this question is -- if someone was converted as a minor and never informed, what's their status later on? The Talmud says you *should* inform them before their bar/bat mitzvah and let the opt out ... but what if you never did? I suggest you simply ask that question, as if this woman is Jewish, so are her children. Of course, assuming the conversion was actually done properly ...

Comment: @JoelK suppose someone does a DNA test and finds with 99.9999% certainly their parents are Barack and Michelle Obama instead of Baruch and Malki Goldbergstein

Comment: In this case it would show that the mother is not related to their grandparents; ie. grandparents are 100% Ashkenazi and the mother is not Ashkenazi.

Comment: @Kingsdaughter613 Maybe I've misunderstood the question. She was converted as an infant and was raised Jewish. The issue is that she thinks that her adoptive parents are her biological parents, and was never given the opporunity to opt out of the conversion?

Comment: @JoelK Yes, that’s the question. I’m wondering what the status of her descendants would be if they find out after her passing.

Comment: If she was never informed of the option to opt out b4 her BM, it seems to me that she continues to be Jewish.  She can 'dissolve' her Jewishness only if she was told about opting out and she indeed follows through the 'dissolving' procedure; whatever that is.

Comment: Dear OP. Why would finding out that she was an infant convert distress her? I don't understand your question.

Comment: @MarsSojourner Because she was unaware of being an adoptee. Most people find discovering that late in life distressing.